# Parentheses matching using stacks and java

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

Here's my code for matching parentheses.THe problem is it always returns false.
I can't see where the mistake is.
topAndpop() returns the top value of the stack and its of type Object.
 Can someone please show me the mistake.

```
public class Matching {
    ArrayStack match_Stack=new ArrayStack();
    Object popped;
    String[] array_match={"{","{","}","}"};
    public boolean matching() throws OverFlowException,EmptyStackException {
        boolean isMatch=false;
        for(int i=0;i< array_match.length;i++) {
            if (array_match[i].equals("{") || array_match[i].equals("[") ||array_match[i].equals("("))   
                match_Stack.push(array_match[i]);

            if(array_match[i].equals("}") || array_match[i].equals("]") ||array_match[i].equals(")") )  {
                if (match_Stack.isEmpty())
                    return false;
                if  (String.valueOf(match_Stack.topAndpop()).equals(String.valueOf(array_match[i]))) {

                    isMatch=true;
                } else {
                    isMatch=false;
                    return isMatch;
                }
            }
        }   
        return isMatch; 
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) throws EmptyStackException,OverFlowException {
        Matching a=new Matching();
        System.out.println(a.matching());
    }
}
```

Comment: What's this? Someone used `String.equals()`... correctly?

Comment: Add some `println` statements to your code and/or debug it. Knowing how to find bugs in your code is one of the first things you should learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always return false because of this line:

```
if (String.valueOf(match_Stack.topAndpop()).equals(String.valueOf(array_match[i]))){
```

The array you are checking is `{"{","{","}","}"}`. The program works for both the `{`s, but when you encounter the first `}`, `match_Stack.topAndpop()` returns `"}"` and so we check if

```
"{".equals("}")
```

Which is false.

To fix this, you need to check if the closing bracket matches the opening one. Here are a few ways of doing this:

- If you take the characters, `'}' - 2` and `']' - 2` are the corresponding opening brackets, but `')' - 1` is the opening parenthesis, because of [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/). That could be one possibility for checking equality.
- You could create a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and map the closing brackets to the opening ones, then see if `yourmapname.get(array_match[i])` is the top element of the stack.
- You could make another method that takes both strings and checks if they are matching.

---

Also, is there any reason why you are using `ArrayStack` instead of `Stack`? Also, is there a reason why you are using an array of strings instead of a `String` or a `char[]`? Also, note that you could do this without a stack by counting opening brackets, subtracting on closing ones, and keeping track of the last type of opening bracket so that you can ensure there are no overlapping brackets (like `([)]`)

Comment: I don't understand.I should check if the popped element matches the one currently in the array_match.I converted the popped to be a String.And array_match is also String.Then why can't I compare them with equals?why is `"{".equals("}")`false

Comment: @sam_rox Is `{` the same as `}`? `String#equals` returns true if and only if the two Strings are exactly equal. `"abc".equals("ABC")` is false. But `"{".equals("{")` is true because the character is the same. `"{".equals("}")` is false because the character is different; they point in opposite directions.

Comment: I've been really foolish.thanks for the answer.I'll try it later.Right now I can't even understand a simple thing like { is not the same as }

Comment: @sam_rox If they were the same, then they would be on the same place on the keyboard, requiring the same key presses. But they are clearly different. And the computer does not know the correspondence between `{` and `}` (all it knows is that there is a number that represents that).

Comment: :I was able to correct it.I added if ..else as                                   `if  (String.valueOf(match_Stack.topAndpop()).equals("{")){
     if (array_match[i].equals("}"))
      isMatch=true;
     else {
      isMatch=false;
      return isMatch;
      }
    
    }`

Answer (score 0):

This condition is wrong:

```
String.valueOf(match_Stack.topAndpop()).equals(String.valueOf(array_match[i]))
```

You're checking whether the closing bracket equals to the opening bracket (which obviously won't be true - `"{".equals("}") == false`) rather than checking whether the two *match* - I'll leave it to you to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Darn, you noticed it just before me.

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not sure why you are using Apache's class for Stack, when Java has a perfectly good generic `Stack`.
2. If you are doing single character comparisons, you do not need String comparison, but I will assume you have reasons for this.
3. As the other answers have mentioned, you are matching opening with closing braces. One way you can fix this is by pushing the opposite type of bracket on.
4. If you are trying to determine whether you have a full, correct matching, the logic is not quite right.

Here's one possible way to rewrite this.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Matching{
    Stack<String> match_Stack=new Stack<String>();
    Object popped;
    String[] array_match={"{","{","}","}"};
    Map<String, String> opposites;

    public boolean matching() {
        // create the mapping
        opposites = new HashMap<String,String>();
        opposites.put("{", "}");
        opposites.put("[", "]");
        opposites.put("(", ")");


        for(int i=0;i< array_match.length;i++){
            String s = array_match[i];
            if (s.equals("{") || s.equals("[") ||s.equals("("))   
                match_Stack.push(opposites.get(s));

            else if (s.equals("}") || s.equals("]") || s.equals(")")) {
                if (match_Stack.isEmpty() || !match_Stack.pop().equals(s))
                    return false;
            }
        }   
        return match_Stack.empty();
    }
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Matching a=new Matching();
        System.out.println(a.matching());

    }
}
```

Here is another implementation that is arguably more intuitive, using `char` instead of `String`.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MatchingChar{
    Stack<Character> match_Stack = new Stack<Character>();
    Object popped;
    String input = "{{}}";
    Map<String, String> opposites;

    public boolean matching() {
        opposites = new HashMap<,String>();
        opposites.put('{', '}');
        opposites.put('[', ']');
        opposites.put('(', ')');


        for(int i=0;i< input.length();i++){
            char s = input.charAt(i);
            if (s == '{' || s == '[' ||s == '(')   
                match_Stack.push(opposites.get(s));

            else if (s == '}' || s == ']' || s == ')') {
                if (match_Stack.isEmpty() || !match_Stack.pop() == s)
                    return false;
            }
        }   

        // If the stack here, that means all grouping operators were matched correctly
        return match_Stack.empty();
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Matching a= new Matching();
        System.out.println(a.matching());
    }
}
```